# PHP can't check for and get json sent data from jquery:

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

When i try it always returns "Error". My code is in one file called index.php
PHP:

```
if($_POST){
    $return="Success.";
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

jQuery:

```
function Save(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./index.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 
                        example:"example",
                        example2:$(".content").text()
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(data){
                    $('#response').append('<p style="color:red;">'+data+'</p>');
                    alert("done");
                }).fail(function(){
                    $('#response').append('<p style="color:red;">Error</p>');
                });
            }
```

THis is the requested network tab and i think all is ok with the POST. Network tab:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Request URL:http://localhost/test/test/test/index.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,bg;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:606
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:_ga=GA1.1.1569762264.1406894118
Host:localhost
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/test/test/test/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
example:example
example2:
<?php
    if(true){
        echo 'ds';
        //das
    }
.test {
    size: 5pt;
}

Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:1641
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 09 Sep 2014 20:03:46 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97
Server:Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1g mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.5.11 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.11
```

And here is the Response tab in the Network tab:

```
"Success."<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text</title>
        <script src="style/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            function Save(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./index.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 
                        filename:"something.php",
                        text:$(".content").text()
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                }).done(function(data){
                    $('#response').append('<p style="color:red;">'+data+'</p>');
                    alert("done");
                }).fail(function(){
                    $('#response').append('<p style="color:red;">Error</p>');
                });
            }

            $(".content").focus(function(){
                $(window).bind('keydown', function(event) {
                    if (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) {
                        switch (String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase()) {
                            case 's':
                            event.preventDefault();
                            Save();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
        <style>
            .content {
                width: 80%;
                height: 80%;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="response"></div>
        <pre><div class="content">
&lt;?php
    if(true){
        echo 'ds';
        //das
    }
.test {
    size: 5pt;
}
        </div></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: When you get this sort of error (knowing that you're removed the print_r statements) you should look at the browser tools, take a look at the response you receive, it will tell you a lot about where your issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client is expecting JSON, you can't print anything other than the JSON. You should exit the script after that:

```
if($_POST){
    $return="Success.";
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Comment: I removed them and again it returns me "Error".

Comment: The `json_decode` calls are probably failing and printing error messages. Check the Network tab of Developer Tools/Firebug to see the full JSON response.

Comment: I checked in the Network tab and all is ok. When i run the code as i edited it in my question it again returns me "Error", so i think that PHP is not accepting the POST. And the problem is not in the JSONs can you tell me why PHP is not accepting the POST?

Comment: What do you see in the Response part of the Network tab?

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: You only posted the Headers tab, what's in the Response tab?

Comment: I added it in the question.

Comment: You see all that HTML after `"Success"`? That's not JSON. You need to change the PHP so it doesn't send that when it's sending JSON.

Comment: I generally find it easiest to use different scripts for sending web pages and for responding to AJAX calls.

Comment: Why PHP is sending this? This "$return=json_encode("Success.");
echo $return;" should send json encoded Success.

Comment: Because the part of your script after that is sending it. You're not exiting the script after echoing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
$return = json_encode(array('success'));
echo $return;
```

Comment: His `.done()` function doesn't expect the response to be an array. If he does this, he needs to change to `data[0]` in the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dummy form to make the POST request via form submission, so you can see the actual output of the PHP script. Add

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of the PHP page to show any errors raised by the PHP. Run the page with your input. Fix any errors until you get the result you are expecting. Then go back to the page with the JavaScript and see if it is working.

Comment: I added it and not came out any kind of errors, notices and etc.

Comment: If your PHP script is not producing any errors, then it must be a problem with your AJAX call.